# Add a button to Internet Explorer 9

Tags: .net, internet-explorer-9

I want to add a button just next to the home button in Internet Explorer 9. When anyone clicks that button he should be able to see a menu that has different icons for different functionality.

How can I do it for Internet Explorer 9? I want to use C# for this. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: see link in my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this [link](http://www.add-in-express.com/programming-internet-explorer/developing-addons.php#command) will help you

**UPDATED:**
You have to create registry entries explained in this Link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735854%28VS.85%29.aspx#

Comment: I don't think this works in IE9 beta yet.  It will add it tot he command band, which is hidden by default now.  They haven't fixed up a way to add it to the list of buttons at the top level yet.  I suspect this will be remedied in future betas?

Answer (score 1):

**If you're looking for simplicity and value your time, [Add-in Express](http://www.add-in-express.com/programming-internet-explorer/) is certainly worth a look.**
To add a toolbar button to IE, all you'll have to do is write a handler for the button's `Click` event in your code. You don't have to worry about [editing the registry, COM objects, or querying interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753588%28VS.85%29.aspx) yourself: all of that is taken care of for you automatically by Add-in Express. Their website is incredibly comprehensive and even offers several video tutorials explaining the process.

Alternatively, [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CorKatIEExtension.aspx) looks like it might do what you want while still saving you from mucking about writing the code to do the dirty work yourself.